# Where is Donkey Mong?

Tags: achievements, borderlands-2

Where does Donkey Mong spawn for the "Definitely an Italian Plumber" achievement?

[image: Donkey Mong]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **the SW corner of Eridium Blight, stay to the right after passing through the gate**. Donkey Mong has a chance of spawning here with or without clearing the area. If you don't see him, try clearing the bullymongs in the area. King Mong and Donkey Mong can spawn together, they do however seem to share spawn locations.

Video by GameFront:

Comment: Ran this area about 40 times got king mong 4 times and donkey mong 0. I seem to be unable to get rare spawns as I've also not gotten jimmy Jenkins after around 100 runs on the wildlife preserve. Guess I just had to complain got him on my 5th try after posting.

Comment: Actually kill King Mong and *then* save and reload, King Mong drops decent stuff :P

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I found him more frequently if you head a little further down the road. Essentially, in between where this video recommends and where you find Mal.

Comment: I also found him close to Mal.

Answer (score 1):

Location given above is correct. However, based on personal experience, both King Mong and Donkey Mong can spawn repeatedly and spawn together.
King Mong spawns in at least two places: just over the Hyperion Gate and in the SW corner of the map by the exit. He spawns 3 out of 5 times for me.
Donkey Mong spawns due west of the Hyperion Gate out of the cliffside. He generally spawns 1 out of 5 times in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I just found him while driving around the east northeast side of the map. I went straight east after fast traveling and crossed the bridge. I took a right after the bridge and he just jumped out of the cliff.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please try to give constructive answers. This answer was already given by others above.